# oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for win32 ia32

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, node-oracledb

I am not able to install node-oracledb for 32bit target in my vue based electron application. Unfortunately I could not found any prebuild at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases
Here is my command

```
npm install oracledb
```

Here is the error.

```
npm ERR! code 87
npm ERR! path C:\Project\proj\node_modules\oracledb
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node package/install.js
npm ERR! oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for win32 ia32
npm ERR! oracledb ERR! Try compiling node-oracledb source code using https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#github

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-16T11_56_41_826Z-debug.log
PS C:\Project\proj>
```

Here is my node

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm current
v16.13.2
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm --version
8.1.2
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm arch
System Default: 64-bit.
Currently Configured: 32-bit.
```

Answer (score 2):

As I have arch 32bit in nvm and I need to install node-oracledb 32bit because of different dependencies. There was no option to use 64 bit at all because of the requirements.

There are two solutions that worked for me.

1- first solution was to install directly from a url

```
npm install https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/download/v5.5.0/oracledb-5.5.0.tgz
```

2- Second solution was to build the oracledb package by yourself for the required environment by following this [link](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#creating-a-node-oracledb-package-from-source-code)

In my case, I have to take care of following things.

1. node should be 32bit in use.
2. MSbuild tools for npm should be set
3. if proxy is used, proxy should be setup for npm.
4. python needs to be installed

afterwards you can install from a file like this

```
npm install file:path/oracledb-5.5.0.tgz
```